# Importing js modules from mjs files webpack4

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js, webpack-4

Ok, so this has been bit of a trip.

On the client side, when importing three.js, why do

```
'mjs' files 'import' : node_modules/three/build/three.module.js
'js' files 'import' : node_modules/three/build/three.js
```

I have a web app sharing some files with node.  The shared files are name 'mjs' to have native ES6 import in node, and the client side uses webpack 4 so these files can be directly imported on the client side as well.

Here is a sample import from one of my mjs files

```
import THREE from 'three' // imports three.js
let { Matrix4, Vector3 } = THREE;
```

On the node side, we need to use the default import statement to reference commonJS files from 'mjs' files.  In my JS files I can reference the classes directly

```
import { Matrix4, Vector3 } from 'three'; // imports three.module.js
```

The problem is, those two statements are not equivalent.  They import different versions of three - not a problem for trivial classes, because the code is the same, but some classes (geometry etc) have static state which is not shared between the different versions of three and my render goes all haywire.

How can I force both MJS and JS files import to be the same file?